# angularjs + jquery : How to access array element within array in Foreach Loop?

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have an object Array 'Vacations'

```
$scope.Vacations = [{Id:'1' ,VacationType = {TypeId='1' ,TypeName = 'test'}}];
```

it contain other object Array 'VacationType' with one set only

I want to extract TypeId

I Did somthing like this :

```
$scope.selectedVacationType = [];
$scope.TypeTd;

$scope.selectedVacationType=Vacations.VacationType;
$scope.TypeTd;= $scope.selectedVacationType[0].Id;
```

But this is not working

What can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$scope.selectedVacationType=Vacations[0].VacationType;`

The `Vacations` represents list of items `[...]`

BTW, your model is wrong, remove `=` and replace with `:`

```
 $scope.Vacations = [{
        Id: '1',
        VacationType : {
           TypeId : '1',
           TypeName : 'test'
        }
    }];
```

**HTML**

```
selectedVacationType: <pre>{{selectedVacationType|json}}</pre>
TypeTd:               <pre>{{TypeTd|json}}</pre>
TypeName:             <pre>{{TypeName|json}}</pre>
```

**controller**

```
    $scope.Vacations = [{
    Id: '1',
    VacationType : {
    TypeId : '1',
        TypeName : 'test'
    }
}];

$scope.selectedVacationType = $scope.Vacations[0].VacationType;
$scope.TypeTd = $scope.selectedVacationType.TypeId;
$scope.TypeName = $scope.selectedVacationType.TypeName;
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLrSu/1/)**</kbd>